# Unable to add an image to a tkinter window

Tags: image, tkinter, png

I am trying to add an image to my tkinter GUI. However I keep receiving errors, in particular my image does not have a 'read' attribute. I have tried this with TIF, GIF and PNG formatted files but none seem to work. I have checked and other seems not to have a problem adding an a image in png format. I have a feeling the problem is obvious but I am missing it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Window(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
   tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)               
   self.master = master
   self.init_window()
def init_window(self):
   self.master.title("Lifespan Data Analyser")
   self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

   path = Image.open('I:/python_work/TemplateRack_GUI.tif')
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = path) #problem is here I think
   panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
   panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
   panel.image=img


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Receive this attribute error:

AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'

AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
path = 'I:/python_work/TemplateRack_GUI.tif'
```

no open
with this change your code works well, try with another tif

Comment: Doing so leads to the following error: OSError: decoder libtiff not available